# LINQ to XML - filter XElement based on its node value compared to another XElement?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want to select COMMISSION elements from B where each COMMISSION element's ID value is not equal to A COMMISSION elements.

Here's my complete Main method:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XElement A = XElement.Parse(
            @"<CONTRACT>
                <COMMISSION>
                    <ID>1</ID>
                    <PRODUCTS>
                        <PRODUCT>A</PRODUCT>
                        <PRODUCT>B</PRODUCT>
                    </PRODUCTS>
                </COMMISSION>
                <COMMISSION>
                    <ID>2</ID>
                    <PRODUCTS>
                        <PRODUCT>C</PRODUCT>
                        <PRODUCT>D</PRODUCT>
                    </PRODUCTS>
                </COMMISSION>
                <COMMISSION>
                    <ID>3</ID>
                    <PRODUCTS>
                        <PRODUCT>E</PRODUCT>
                        <PRODUCT>F</PRODUCT>
                    </PRODUCTS>
                </COMMISSION>
            </CONTRACT>");

        XElement B = XElement.Parse(
            @"<CONTRACT>
                <COMMISSION>
                    <ID>3</ID>
                    <PRODUCTS>
                        <PRODUCT>E</PRODUCT>
                        <PRODUCT>F</PRODUCT>
                    </PRODUCTS>
                </COMMISSION>
            </CONTRACT>");

        // This *should* only return COMMISSION elements from B.
        // Rather, it returns the same B COMMISSION twice: once for the COMMISSION
        // element (ID=3) in B, and once for the COMMISSION element (ID=3) in A. 
        var bOnly =
            from excluded in A.Descendants("COMMISSION")
            let included = 
                from b in B.Descendants("COMMISSION")
                where b.Element("ID").Value != excluded.Element("ID").Value
                select b
            select new XElement("CONTRACT", included);

        // Print results 
        foreach (var v in bOnly)            
        {
            Console.WriteLine(v);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

As I state in my code, rather than getting the desired output:

```
            <CONTRACT>
                <COMMISSION>
                    <ID>3</ID>
                    <PRODUCTS>
                        <PRODUCT>E</PRODUCT>
                        <PRODUCT>F</PRODUCT>
                    </PRODUCTS>
                </COMMISSION>
            </CONTRACT>
```

I get:

```
        <CONTRACT>
            <COMMISSION>
                <ID>3</ID>
                <PRODUCTS>
                    <PRODUCT>E</PRODUCT>
                    <PRODUCT>F</PRODUCT>
                </PRODUCTS>
            </COMMISSION>
        </CONTRACT>
        <CONTRACT>
            <COMMISSION>
                <ID>3</ID>
                <PRODUCTS>
                    <PRODUCT>E</PRODUCT>
                    <PRODUCT>F</PRODUCT>
                </PRODUCTS>
            </COMMISSION>
        </CONTRACT>
        <CONTRACT/>
```

I don't know why COMMISSION w/ ID=3 is returned twice. Help! Thank you. Please keep in mind, ID is the only element value I want to compare. If A has ID=3 w/ different products than B's ID=3, then I'd expect my result to show nothing.

MY FINAL SOLUTION:

```
           // Question: How do I only get COMMISSIONs from B that aren't in A?
        // Requirement: I only want to compare ID between A and B COMMISSION sets, 
        //   so if A ID=3 has products that are different from B ID=3, the query treats the
        //   two COMMISSIONs as the same so long as their ID is the same.
        // Answer: (Steps 1 thru 3)        

        // Step 1) Get COMMISSIONs from B equalling COMMISSIONs from A on ID       
        var same =
            from a in A.Descendants("COMMISSION")
            join b in B.Descendants("COMMISSION")
            on a.Element("ID").Value equals b.Element("ID").Value
            select a;

        // Step 2) Get all COMMISSIONs from B
        var all = from b in B.Descendants("COMMISSION")
                    select b;

        // Step 3) Get COMMISSIONs that are only in B
        var different = all.Cast<XNode>().Except(same.Cast<XNode>(), new XNodeEqualityComparer());

        // Print results 
        foreach (var v in different)            
        {
            Console.WriteLine(v);
        }
```

Comment: I believe you are getting two results not because there is a COMMISSION element in each set, but rather because the single element in B doesn't match the elements with IDs {1, 2} in set A.  If you had 100 mismatched elements in set A, you should get the element with ID 3 printed 100 times.

Comment: I don't think that's quite right. If you look at my result, you'll see there's a third (empty) CONTRACT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed your LINQ query to the following

```
var bOnly =
    from a in A.Descendants("COMMISSION")
    join b in B.Descendants("COMMISSION")
    on a.Element("ID").Value equals b.Element("ID").Value
    select a;
```

And output looks good now, no duplicates:

```xml
<COMMISSION>
    <ID>3</ID> 
    <PRODUCTS>
        <PRODUCT>E</PRODUCT> 
        <PRODUCT>F</PRODUCT> 
    </PRODUCTS>
</COMMISSION>
```

Also I fixed query from your example, it works now properly too:

```
var bOnly =
    from b in B.Descendants("COMMISSION")
    let same =
        from a in A.Descendants("COMMISSION")
        where a.Element("ID").Value == b.Element("ID").Value
        select b
    select new XElement("CONTRACT", same);
```

Comment: I actually only want the UNIQUE commission elements (only focusing on ID), not the joined commission elements on id. However, it's not your fault I mistyped my question. You helped me solve my problem - thank you! I'll edit my question to include my complete solution.

Comment: @DavidAlanCondit ah yeah, I see now. Anyway glad I could help!